# PHP/MYSQL Session - Print Current Username

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

I am using a simple PHP/MYSQL login system using sessions and I need to print the username for the person currently logged in to the session.

The current code I am using to do this is:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

$res=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_row($res);
print_r($userRow)
?>
```

But the output of this is:

> Array ( [0] => USERNAME )

While I would like it to be:

> USERNAME

How would I achieve this, or is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is in array. you have to access the index to get the value like this,

```
echo $userRow['username'];
```

I would suggest to store the username in session and access it directly instead of accessing from database everytime.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "name here";

echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

**EDIT**

```
echo $userRow[0];
```

this should help you.

Comment: using echo $userRow['username']; returned a blank page

Comment: u edited your question?? try like this, `$userRow[0]`

Comment: Sorry, when I edited it I thought that no one had answered yet, the new answer worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $userRow['username'];
```

Try this out.